# how to calculate the predicted motion vector in ARPS

Tags: algorithm, video-encoding

I'm doing a video homework in which you program one of the famous video compression algorithms, I chose ARPS(adaptive rood pattern search).

Now if I understand it right I must first divide the image into macroblocks, I've already done that, second calculate the pmv(predicted motion vector) by taking the motion vector of the left neighboring macroblock(type D, there are other types in which you take the above or left-above etc, according to some paper they don't differ much in quality).

Last use pmv to calculate the mv of the current macroblock.

If I understand it correctly I have to calculate the first column of macroblocks using other algorithms(NTSS or FSS or etc) and then use that column to calculate the rest.

What will happen if my first column didn't move ? pmv=(0,0) and applying the algorithm as I understand it from wikipedia results in all mvs being (0,0) (aka first column didn't change=nothing changed !!!)

I doubt I understand the algorithm correctly and for some reason many papers don't address those issues, so can you shed some light on it ? I can implement it very well after that.

### PS

this is a university homework and I'm at software-engineering department (not AI department) so no AI algorithms please .

Answer (score 0):

As I know strength of ARPS algorithm is adaptive rood size, which base on predicted motion vector (mv). Rood is used as the first step of this method, and may dramatical reduce over estimation by jumping in the right place. Second step is to fine the best point(s) by small diamond or other fixed patterns you like. 
So if you predict zero mv, you simple apply fine estimation (second step). 
In practice, zero mv mean small metric value of estimated block (by SAD or other metric). Natural static pictures always have some deviation of adjacent (in temporal plane) samples and any metric produce some value. It is decision of you implementation marking this block by zero moving or with small motion vector.
About the column in you implementation. For first block in the non first row you may use mv of above block. that reduce you total calculations. 
 
In any case, you may check is you changes of implementation good or bad, by apply motion compensation (inverse of motion estimation) and calculate with original picture by calculating the [PSNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio) metric.

Comment: well I calculated mv of the middle column(using FSS) and used those for the rest of columns, I applied compensation and the results were very good(better than FSS)